# Issue related to css for Mozila and IE

Tags: html, css

I have following css:

```
.tabStyle
        {
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #E4E4E4) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        }
```

That works great in Mozila fire fox but dosn't work in IE and Google Chrome.

how can i achieve it in IE and Chrome>?

Comment: It's really not so hard http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gradient+crossbrowser (-1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete CSS for each browser that supports it:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #e4e4e4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#e4e4e4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#e4e4e4 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#e4e4e4 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#e4e4e4 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#e4e4e4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to comment out, styles with `-moz` prefix will work only in mozilla. In chrome in order to make some fancy stuff there are `-webkit` prefixed styles. For ie styling you have to use something like this `filter:progid...` or `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(sProperties)`. I strongly recommend you not to use the above techniques but achive your goals using standard css.

For example if you want to make a gradient background you could save the gradient with dimensions 1x40, i.e. 1px width and 40 pixels of gradient. Then apply as follows

```
.myGradientClass {
    background: url(../images/myGradient.png) repeat-x;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
}

<div class="myGradientClass"></div>
```